# TaskManager: Task "firstTask" executed but looks like it's not defined. Make sure "TaskManager.defineTask" is called during initialization phase

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, expo, taskmanager

I'm running an EAS app where I have to use Expo-Task-Manager to handle background locations. When my app builds, I get hit with this error:

```
TaskManager: Task "firstTask" has been executed but looks like it is not defined. Please make 
sure that "TaskManager.defineTask" is called during initialization phase.
```

Below is my code for executing the Task Manager in my app, but I am struggling to see where I would call it in an "initialization phase."

```
import * as TaskManager from 'expo-task-manager'
import * as BackgroundFetch from 'expo-background-fetch'
import * as Location from 'expo-location'

const LOCATION_TASK_NAME = 'background-location-task'

useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(()=>{

       const requestBackgroundPermissions = async() =>{
       const {status} = await Location.requestBackgroundPermissionsAsync()
         if(status === 'granted'){
           await Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync('firstTask',{
             accuracy: Location.Accuracy.Balanced,
       });
     }
     requestBackgroundPermissions()

    },
    [],
   ),
 )
```

//Outside of the useFocusEffect

```
TaskManager.defineTask('firstTask',({data,errror})=>{
    if(error){
      alert('Something went wrong with background locations')
    }
    if(data){
      alert('Something went right with background locations')
      const{locations} = data
    }
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, if you run into this issue, try moving your Task Manager into your App.js file. When the app loads, the Task Manager will be a part of the initialization phase. If you have any issues, feel free to reach out, but it should look something like this:

```
import React from "react"
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native'
import * as TaskManager from 'expo-task-manager'
import * as BackgroundFetch from 'expo-background-fetch'
import * as Location from 'expo-location'

const LOCATION_TASK_NAME = 'background-location-task'

TaskManager.defineTask('firstTask',({data,errror})=>{
    if(error){
      alert('Something went wrong with background locations')
    }
    if(data){
      alert('Something went right with background locations')
      const{locations} = data
    }
})

export default function App(){

return <AppFile/>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used this solution in my `index.js` file and it works just fine

```
...
import * as BackgroundFetch from 'expo-background-fetch';
import * as TaskManager from 'expo-task-manager';
import { store } from './src/store';
import { getNotificationCount } from './src/store/actions/NotificationsActions';

const FETCH_TASKNAME = 'BACKGROUND-NOTIFICATION-TASK';
const INTERVAL = 1;


export async function registerFetchTask() {
    TaskManager.defineTask(FETCH_TASKNAME, ({ data, error, executionInfo }) => {
        console.log('BACKGROUND-NOTIFICATION-TASK', data, error, executionInfo);
        if (store) {
            const profile = store.getState().myProfileSlice.profile;
            profile.id && store.dispatch(getNotificationCount(profile.id));
        }
    });

    const status = await BackgroundFetch.getStatusAsync();
    switch (status) {
        case BackgroundFetch.BackgroundFetchStatus.Restricted:
        case BackgroundFetch.BackgroundFetchStatus.Denied:
            console.log("Background execution is disabled");
            return;
        default: {
            console.log("Background execution allowed");

            let tasks = await TaskManager.getRegisteredTasksAsync();
            if (tasks.find(f => f.taskName === FETCH_TASKNAME) == null) {
                console.log("Registering task");
                await BackgroundFetch.registerTaskAsync(FETCH_TASKNAME);

                tasks = await TaskManager.getRegisteredTasksAsync();
                console.log("Registered tasks", tasks);
            } else {
                console.log(`Task ${FETCH_TASKNAME} already registered, skipping`);
            }

            await BackgroundFetch.setMinimumIntervalAsync(INTERVAL);
        }
    }
}

registerFetchTask();

registerRootComponent(App);
```